# Google Map click event outside polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've looked around and realized that I can define a polygon, and have a click event that only happens when a user clicks within the polygon like this:

```
polygonClick = google.maps.event.addListener( polygon, "click", function( evt ) {
    function();
} );
```

What I would like to do is to have a listener that listens everywhere OTHER than inside the polygon, something like this:

```
polygonClick = google.maps.event.addListener( !polygon, "click", function( evt ) {
    function();
} );
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Create a listener on the *map*.

```
mapClick = google.maps.event.addListener( map, "click", function( evt ) {
    function();
} );
```

Comment: not sure, why it was not accepted; let me at least upvote it (for the effort)